# Custom column sorting in Dojo Datagrid programmatically

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I have created a `dojox.grid.datagrid` programmatically and I need custom sorting on the columns.
For this I tried using `ItemFileWriteStore.comparatorMap['field'] = comparatorFunc`. But my comparator function is never called.

Any idea on what I am missing here?

Comment: probably someone can post a jsfiddle for this. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: What your `comparatorFunc` looks like?

Comment: problem was with my structure of comparator func. Issue got fixed.

Comment: @Lokn Post your answer let others learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have done custom sorting on data grid. (Dojo-1.4)
sample code here:

```
function(response, ioArgs){                                                             
                    queryGrid.queryOptions={ignoreCase:true};
                    queryGrid.setStore(new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(response[responseResult]));  
                    setCustomSort(queryGrid.store);


..

}

function setCustomSort(store){
            if(!store.comparatorMap){
                store.comparatorMap = {};
            }

            store.comparatorMap["unresolvedHrs"] = sortNum;
            store.comparatorMap["tat"] = sortNum;
        }

function sortNum(a, b){
            var _a = convertTimeToNum(a);
            var _b = convertTimeToNum(b);
            var ret = 0;
            if (_a > _b) {
                ret = 1;
            }
            if (_a < _b) {
                ret = -1;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Here convertTimeToNum is to convert time format value to number in minutes.